# Exit from switch C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Player.h"
using namespace std;

void PlayerMenu();


int main() {


    int z;
    cout << "Please press 0 to see the PLayers Menu. " << endl;
    cin >> z;
    while (z == 0) {
        PlayerMenu();

    }

    cout << " Now You're Functional Lets get started. ";


};
void PlayerMenu()
{
    char ch;
    int num;

    do {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\n\n\n\t Player Menu";
        cout << "\n\n1 Wallet Balance  ";
        cout << "\n\n2 Player Invetory";
        cout << "\n\n3 To Exit";
        cin >> ch;
        system("cls");
        switch (ch)
        {
        case '1':
            cout << "Your Balance at the moment is ..."<<endl;
            cout << "\n";
            Bank();
            break;

            //Show Wallet Balance
        case '2':

            cout << "Here is your Inventory"<<endl;
            cout << "\n";
            break;

            //Show Inventory

        case '3':
            cout << " Bye.\n";
            break;
            //exit i'VE TRIED bREKA BUT it will not go back to the main source code or main method
        }

        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();


    } while (ch != '3');//If not 1 or 2 or 3 will ignore it
}
```

I tried break statements, but the break method will not exit to the main method and run the last following statement. I would like to also run methods inside of the case to case so when a player is selecting 1 it will show the balance of the player.  Also when the player inputs a value of 2 it will show a vector of weapons bought.

Comment: *I tried break statements, but the break method will not exit to the main method and run the last following statement.* - what does it mean? Why would it exit to `main`? It will "exit" the `switch` statement which is inside a loop.

Comment: I am trying to make the case statement if the value is 3 it will get out of the switch and then display the _cout_ statement following the first while loop.

Comment: BTW, if the User presses 0 to answer the prompt, the program will never end.  The variable `z` is never changed inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Your menu function will not print anything except the menu, if the User enters '4' or '%'.

Answer (score 5):

Use `return` instead of `break` to exit from the current function. You then don't need the `while (ch != '3')`. Instead, you can just use an infinite loop:

```
while (true) {
    // ...

    case '3':
        cout << " Bye.\n";
        return;
    }

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

You can also use `for (;;)` instead of `while (true)`, but that's just a stylistic choice.

Also, don't call `PlayerMenu()` in a loop in main. Just do:

```
int main()
{
    int z;
    cout << "Please press 0 to see the PLayers Menu. " << endl;
    cin >> z;
    if (z == 0) {
        PlayerMenu();
    }

    cout << " Now You're Functional Lets get started. ";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`break` in this context exits the `switch`. If you wish to exit the *function*, you will need to `return` instead.

Comment: The OP's actual problem is the infinite loop in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `PlayerMenu()` function is exiting just fine. The problem is in `main()`:

```
while (z == 0) {
    PlayerMenu();

}
```

There is nothing in the loop that modifies `z`, so it never exits. It just keeps going back to the menu forever.

I don't know if you intended to loop there or just test it with an `if`.